# Rotation field is missing in Layer Properties > Symbology > Advanced in QGIS 3.10. How to fix this?

Tags: layers, symbology, style, qgis-3

[image: Rotation Field Missing]

In the layer properties under symbology- advanced properties, the Rotation filed is missing.

Answer (score 2):

The Rotation property is not (has never been?) in Advanced properties, but among the normal properties, as you can see in the screenshot you have provided:

[image]

Comment: I would like to use the expression string from the rotation field. 
It is only available in the advanced properties but not in the rotation property.

Comment: @Kavya, if I understood correctly, you need to use the "Data defined override" tool (see the tool inon enclosed in a red square) which is available for almost all the properties/options, included the Rotation property.
Please refer to the user manual at https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#data-defined-override-setup

Comment: Thank you so much, Andrea. I am very new to QGIS. I must have missed going through the manual.